# Append <div> tag randomly on page in each refresh at different place

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have collection of 2 types of `<div>`s on a page.

Collection 1 of type:

```
<div class="feature">content 1</div>
<div class="feature">content 2</div>
and so on.
```

Collection 2 of type:

```
<div class="native-content-1">My native code 1</div>
<div class="native-content-2">My native code 2</div>
```

On each page load a div should be randomly picked from collection 1 and appended to a div randomly selected from collection 2.

Comment: Can you show the code that you need help with?

Comment: Do you want to append or replace ? You have specified both.

Comment: There are quite a few different approaches to this, one way would be to set up multiple divs on the page and then give them each a numbered data attribute. Then just use Javascript to generate a random number on each refresh and append the html to the div with the attribute which matches the random number.

Comment: i want to replace the few placements
<code>
<div class="feature">content 1</div>
<div class="feature">content 2</div>
<div class="feature">content 3</div>
<div class="feature">content 4</div>
<div class="feature">content 5</div>
<div class="feature">content 6</div>

//my native code 
<div class="native-content-1">
My native code 
</div>
<div class="native-content-2">
My native code 
</div>
</code>

i need to replace the feature divs with native-content div's in each refresh random ,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am Using a random function which will return a number from given range.

I hope this is what you expected:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  function onPageLoad() {

    var no_of_features = $(".feature").length
    var selectedRandomFeature = getRandomInt(0, no_of_features - 1);


    var no_of_natives = $("[class^='native-content-']").length;
    var selectedRandomnative = getRandomInt(1, no_of_natives)
    $($(".feature")[selectedRandomFeature]).append($(".native-content-" +   selectedRandomnative))



  }

  function getRandomInt(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  onPageLoad();
});
```

```css
.feature {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 20px;
}
[class^='native-content-'] {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="native-content-1">My native code 1</div>
<div class="native-content-2">My native code 2</div>
<div class="native-content-3">My native code 3</div>
<div class="feature">content 1</div>
<div class="feature">content 2</div>
<div class="feature">content 3</div>
<div class="feature">content 4</div>
<div class="feature">content 5</div>
```

Comment: Thanks Roshan ,

But in my page i am not able to append the ID for each div from back end  . so is there   any other way to do this

Comment: Ya, it is possible.Will update it.